# Debian-based servers can authenticate users on OpenLDAP when RH-based servers cannot

Tags: openldap, centos8, debian-buster

I'm putting centralized authentication in my LAN infrastructure. The LDAP server is up and running, and all Debian/Ubuntu servers manage to authenticate users against the LDAP.

Now, all my CentOS8/Fedora32 machines just cannot. First, the client-side configuration is based on sssd, which differs a lot, but even then, once I've completed the client config, I can, typing `id $USER` get all of the user's UID, GIDs, etc, so I know that the config is sane.

Now, from the newly-configured as root, let's say I do this:
`# su - USER1` --> succeeds, without asking a passwd (of course), creates the home dir
`# su - USER2` --> (as root, again), succeeds again
now... as USER2:
`USER2$ su - USER1` --> will prompt for USER1's password, and will fail.

From any other machine:
`ssh USER1@LDAPCLIENT` --> fails
same for any other user.

This makes me think that there might be something in the way that RH-based machines interpret passwords, regardless of the backend. I'm no expert in PAM, SSSD or any security mechanism, so I do not know.

Anyone knows enough about SSSD, PAM, NSS on RH vs Debian to enlighten me ?

Comment: What is your sssd's config? What is your equivalent libpam_ldapd/libpam_ldap config?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you've got sssd integrated into nsswitch but not pam.

If `grep sss /etc/pam.d/*` yields nothing, run `sudo authconfig --enablesssdauth --update`.

Comment: No, pam_sss.so is present in /etc/pam.d/{fingerprint,password,system}-auth

Would you need config files that I'd publish on gist to clear this up ? I'm totally at loss here. I totally rule out the LDAP, as I said, debian-based machines and VMs authentify against it.